# How to manipulate an image to have the depth effect on iOS16

Tags: ios, swift, image, ios16

What kind of images (other than photos taken on iPhone), can get the depth effect on iOS16?

What should be modified or added to a photo like this:

[image]

So it could have the depth effect that photos taken on iPhone have, like this.

[image]

Strangly, even though the image of the fish is not appropriate for depth effect, the subject can be easily extracted with a long press, like it is described [here](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/isolate-copy-share-subjects-photos/). The following subject is received:

[image]

Comment: @aciniglio This is the correct answer. Go ahead and put it down as the answer to get the points and the upvotes you deserve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, if you can extract the subject, you can use it for depth on the lockscreen. I've noticed that it will only cover up a small percentage of the time (e.g. just the bottom of the numbers in 10:41) before disabling depth effect for a photo. Try zooming and panning the fish so that it just barely covers the time. I don't think it will let the subject cover the complete height of the time.

Comment: what helped me additionally is to understand that this effect only works if you have NO widgets on your lockscreen but only the clock